# How to restart specific OpenVPN services using "service"

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openvpn

I've got two different OpenVPN servers running on a box and I want to restart one of them (and leave the other untouched). I know I can restart all OpenVPN service using `service openvpn restart`, but then that restarts all OpenVPN services.

Is there a way to restart a specific OpenVPN server using the `service` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `/etc/init.d/openvpn` script (which is what gets executed by `/usr/sbin/service`) does not offer any options to do it (at least with ubuntu-10.04), the answer is no.

But since it is all scripts, you can just edit /etc/init.d/openvpn and add something like

```
named-restart)
  log_action_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC $2"
  PIDFILE="/var/run/openvpn.${2}.pid"
  NAME=$2
  log_daemon_msg "  Stopping VPN '$NAME'"
  stop_vpn
  sleep 1
  log_daemon_msg "  Restarting VPN '$NAME'"
  start_vpn
  if test -z "$PIDFILE" ; then
    log_warning_msg "  VPN $2 is not running."
  fi
  ;;
```

after the

```
case "$1" in
```

dirctive. Later, you can simply call `service openvpn named-restart <vpn-name>`.

Answer (score 2):

the cmd "service openvpn restart" don't do distinction, it restart the services. I think an solution might be to reload the service. It will not cut the service doing, but reload the configuration file. So It might do the trick.

Else I don't think you can restart one of you vpn without restart the other with the service cmd.